# Google static map picture not net/clear

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-static-api

Sometimes when I use Google static map API, Google returns a picture not net/clear. I really don't know why, I use Google API in php `foreach` (5 iterations maximum). I have Google API key, and I use php `sleep` function in my loop (2 seconds between each iteration).

Two first pictures in my loop are good, last 3 pictures are bad. Maybe Google doesn't like API request in `foreach` ?

Bad picture

[image]

Other bad

[image]

Good picture in the same loop
[image]

**Code sample**

In my `foreach` I do this :

```
$list_map_src = array();

foreach($list_ad as $ad){
    $projet_ad = urlencode(utf8_encode($ad));
    $params = 'zoom=4&center='.$projet_ad.'&maptype=raodmap&size=200x200&scale=2&key=MY_KEY';

    google_map_url = "https://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?".$params;      

    $list_map_src[] = $google_map_url;  
}
```

In my `HTML` I use `$list_map_src` to set `img` `src` tag

Comment: Could you provide any sample codes for this one?

Comment: Yes sure I have edit my post @rafon

Comment: All the code you've given us so far is doing is adding some URLs into an array... what do you then do with that array?

Comment: Yes, in my `html` (I use `smarty`). I use this array to set img src tag like this for example : `<img width="180px" height="150px;" src="{$list_map_src[0]}" />` @duncan

Answer (score 0):

First, you should check your parameter names.

I've tried to do this on my end, and it seems to work.

I've hardcoded some places for testing purposes. Please use my code as a reference

```
<?php

$list_ad = array( array('src' => 'Montbard, France'), array('src' => 'Toulouse, France'), array('src' => 'Luxembourg') );

foreach( $list_ad as $key ) {
    $project_ad = urlencode( utf8_encode( $key['src'] ) );
    $params = 'center='.$project_ad.'&zoom=4&maptype=roadmap&size=200x200&scale=2&key=YOUR_API_KEY';
    echo '<img src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?'.$params.'" />';
    sleep(2);
}
```